# Will this hard drive work with my 2009 15 macbook pro unibody?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, hardware, hardware-recommendation

Western Digital WD Scorpio Black 750 GB SATA 3 GB/s 7200 RPM 16 MB Cache Internal Bulk/OEM 2.5-Inch Mobile Hard Drive

i need to know if this hard drive will work with my computer?

I have 8 GB of memory (maxed out)

I also need to know also if this is a good hard drive.

Has any one used it? Is it quiet? Does it over heat?

Answer (score 1):

No experience with that drive but you may encounter issues with that model MBP  and any replacement drives. Downgrading the firmware may fix the issue or you any need to replace the SATA cable. You may not want to do either in advance but don't be surprised if you encounter a problem.